# Redirect path nginx with location

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I want to implement multiple redirections, for example:

I did this:

```
location = /about {
  return 301 /es_CR;
}
```

And is correct but a need /about, /about-us and /about.php to redirect to the same domain (/es_CR) but I need to do this in just one location, I guess something like this:

```
location = /about(*) {
  return 301 /es_CR;
}
```

Any body knows how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it in one location block, you can use multiple blocks

```
location = /about {
  return 301 /es_CR;
}
location = /about-us {
  return 301 /es_CR;
}
location = /about.php {
  return 301 /es_CR;
}
```

Alternately can do it with a regular expression, something like this should work, though I haven't tested it. This regex matches everything with "about" in the URL.

```
location ~* about {
  return 301 /es_CR;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can construct regex that will match about, about-us and about.php with:

```
location ~ /(about|\/about-us|\.php) {
            return 301 https://www.example.com;
}
```

Hope that helps.